# Add to MySQLquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to add a WHERE to my query when a gender is selected in a form.

I'm using bindParam to use one dropdownmenu to get the Year but I would like a second bindParam that inserts a 'AND Gender =' to the query and a '$_GET['dropdowngender'] to fill that.

I want to use an if statement to look if the dropdownmenu is being used and if a gender is being selected that the information is being added to the query.

```
<?php

@include ('conn.php');

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT Name, MAX(Count) AS MaxCount, ZIPcode, Year FROM Name_Data WHERE Year = :year AND Name_Data.Count = ( SELECT MAX( Count ) FROM Name_Data AS f WHERE f.id = Name_Data.id ) GROUP BY ZIPcode");

$query->bindParam(':jaar', $_GET['dropdownyear'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 30);

$query->execute();

$result = $query->fetchAll (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

$jsonResult = json_encode($result);

echo $jsonResult;

?>
```

this is my index page

```
<form method="post" action="#" id="form">
    <select name="dropdownyear" id="menuyear">
        <option selected>Choose a year</option>
    </select>
    <select name="dropdowngender" id="menugender">
            <option value="M">Male</option>
    <option value="F">Female</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

my jquery script

```
$( "#form" )
.change(function(){
$(".marker").empty();
var SelectYear= $("#menuyear option:selected").text();

    $.getJSON( "sql.php",  { dropdownjaar: SelectYear }, function(jsonData) {    
        console.log( jsonData );

        $.each( jsonData, function(key,row) {
            var newDiv=$('<div>');
            var Content = row ['Name'] + ' ';
            newDiv.text(Content);
    }); // each

    }); //get json
}); // change function
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
$query = "SELECT Name, MAX(Count) AS MaxCount, ZIPcode, Year 
          FROM Name_Data 
          WHERE Year = :year ";
if( isset( $_GET['dropdowngender'] ) {
    $query = $query . " AND gender = :gender ";
}

$query = $query . " AND Name_Data.Count = 
         ( SELECT MAX( Count ) FROM Name_Data AS f 
           WHERE f.id = Name_Data.id 
         ) GROUP BY ZIPcode";

$query->bindParam(':year', $_GET['dropdownyear'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
if( isset( $_GET['dropdowngender'] ) {
    $query->bindParam(':gender', $_GET['dropdowngender'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work, is there anything in the jqueryscript that needs to be changed?

Comment: @user3327797: Unless you specify an option, by default the first option from `select` list will be submitted. So it must be working.